# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement nuget causing System.PlatformNotSupportedExceptionSystem.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: web-applications, active-directory, azure-service-fabric, directoryservices, account-management

I have a web solution that has the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement nuget package installed so I could use the directory services API to check for user group membership. I deployed the solution to the local service fabric Windows 11 for testing out the group membership calls but it is throwing the following exception.

Exception:System.PlatformNotSupportedExceptionSystem.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform. at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType) ...